# Visual Studio 2015 Graphics Debugger has trouble with spaced usernames

Tags: debugging, graphics, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

Today I've installed Visual Studio Community 2015 in my computer. I'm working with the Graphics Analyzer, which is very easy to use, but I can't get the "Apply shader changes" feature to work. Supposing my username is "My Username", a error like this appears:

```
Too many files specified ('Username\AppData\Local\Temp\{c7e2ecaf-5adf-4b71-8f6e-e1fc00ca00e8}\DisassemblyUpdate.csd' was the last one), use /? to get usage information
```

I think it's probably because it tries to open something like

```
C:\Users\My Username\AppData\Local\Temp\{c7e2ecaf-5adf-4b71-8f6e-e1fc00ca00e8}\DisassemblyUpdate.csd
```

but without quotation marks.

Is there any way to solve this issue? Any way to change the temp dir for VS? If I can't get it to work then I'll try to create a new user account, but that takes very long and I'd want to avoid doing that.

---

UPDATE: I've already tried many times to create another account, but I can't. Maybe it's a bug in Windows 10? Gonna try later again.

---

UPDATE 2: I've managed to enable the administrator account (even though it's bugged as f***: Start Menu doesn't open, can't open settings, fonts don't have any antialiasing, ...). I can now edit shaders "on the go" normally. But because the account is too bugged, I can't use it every time.